# Objective C Regex- Numbers in NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a number of NSStrings I need to parse/regex and get the numbers 187,215; 181,170; 69,63; etc etc out.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"187";i:1;s:3:"215";}
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"181";i:1;s:3:"170";}
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"69";i:1;s:2:"63";}
```

Anyone can help out?

Comment: Something as simple as `"\d+"`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ios and everything to do with what did you try to do that isn't working? And only a little to do with Regular Expressions. Don't expect people do write code for you simply to boost their own egos. (Some will) go read the book Mastering Regular Expressions up to chapter 3. If you still have no idea what to do, change jobs.

Comment: @Andrews were you able to resolve this issue?  If the answer was helpful please make sure to mark it as correct.

Comment: yes Walls. sorry for the delay, I was out for couple of days. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. The items you are trying to grab are only numbers (with no other chars inside).
   If you know your numbers (or whatever inside the quotes) is what you need, you can search for the quotes that surround them.
2. The quotes are only used to contain the item (digits) you are searching for.

**If you want numbers and surrounding quotes** 
`"\d+?"` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/SzA7k82ehk)

This will grab any digits (one or more digit due to the `+`) inside of quotes.  Since regex is normally "greedy", adding the `?` after the `+` will make it "non-greedy", or it will stop processing and looking for digits after it hits the NEXT quote instead of processing until it find the last quote.

**If you want just the numbers**
`(?<=")\d+?(?=")` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/8zR7Szjy0o)

This is similar to the previous regex, the only difference is the exclusion of the quotes from the returned item.  Including the quotes in the regex will match them positively and then return them back.  This regex uses positive look-ahead and look-behinds to ensure that the pattern we are looking for `\d+?` is preceded by a quote and followed by a quote.

Comment: Thanks a lot Walls. Did not know about Rubular. this is great!